# Advice on using one application as a front-end for logging into another application

Tags: java, spring, security, postgresql, grails

I've written an app in Grails using Spring Security that can handle
all of the user oriented tasks like login, logout, reset password,
and new user registration with email verification. The app also can
manage user roles and the like. It has it's own postgres database
to store user information.

I want to use the Grails app as a front-end for another 
legacy Tomcat GWT app that uses Spring Security
and that only has login/logout, and it depends on user data being populated
through LDAP. It has no user registration front end, or reset password
functionality. The legacy app has it's own postgres database with user
information.

I plan on running two instances of Tomcat on two different ports
on the same machine to host these two apps. Both apps will have
access to all databases.

The question is, what is the best way to have the Grails app accept
logins, and then pass the user on to the legacy app? Am I describing Single Sign On?

The legacy app has code for preauthentication, but it looks to me like just passing
a user name through the request header is not secure! How would the legacy app
know that the user is really logged in? I've been reading a little about
Secure Remote Passwords, and I'm wondering if it might be a way to handle
securely logging into the Grails app, and passing off control to the legacy app?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to change the legacy app.. i.e. the portions that check to see if a user has logged in?

Comment: Yes, I have the code of the legacy app. The answer suggesting using the 'remember me' feature sounds suprisingly easy! Would I have a problem because the cookie would be set in the Grails app, and not the legacy app? The 2 apps would be reached through the nginx web server, depending on the URL the user types in.

Answer (score 1):

When you make login in the frontend app configure spring_security to set a "remember me" cookie for the legacy app.

The user login in the frontend and then when open the legacy up it's auto logged in.

This is the more simple solution and have many limits but works!

Answer (score 1):

I think you guessed right regarding single sign on. Check out the CAS plugin for grails. It provides SSO for multiple spring security enabled apps.

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-cas